# Ignore space after predictive text selection in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, textview, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I found something similar to my problem checkout here but it does not work for me: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26482036/why-does-shouldchangetextinrange-get-called-multiple-times-using-predictive-inpu/26789344#26789344)

Thid UITextView delegate method calls twice If we tap on predictive text
1st call insert text 2nd call insert space after if

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool
```

I found one hack:

```
if text.count > 1 { return false }
```

But this logic failed when user tap on single character predictive text

I am doing some customizations in this method e.g. mentions support so after doing some work I update attributedText of TextView on mainThread so before setting attributedText to the textView this method get call for space in predictive text selection case and at that time previous text is not setup yet so it will insert just space.

Two things comes in my mind, somehow handle the call of this method that it should not call twice until text is set to textView

Second somehow ignore the space after predictive text.

```
if text == " " { return false }
```

We also can not do this because after that user will not be able to insert spaces.

Predictive texts:

[image]